# Reset cookie life and session Id in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to reset the session cookie, and its life, when the user logs in in PHP. 
It sounds pretty trivial but I am still struggling to make it right.

When the page is loaded, the user may or may not alreay have a cookie. If he has one, I want to delete it and reset the sessionId, if not I will just give him a new one with the proper life. I cannot use `session_status()` because of the PHP version I am using.

Here is what I came up with but it does not work when the user already has a session cookie.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) setcookie(session_name(), false);
session_set_cookie_params(2678400); // sets cookie life to one month
session_start();
// do stuff
```

When the user is logged in, the old cookie is normally deleted but `session_start()` does not deliver a new cookie. It there a way to force delivering a new cookie without having to manually implement the logic of session id creation?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to destroy/restart the session on the PHP side, you just have to send a new cookie to the client. Just call `setcookie()` again (with the existing session id), that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Much easier this way. For those who want to know how I implemented it: `if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()], time() + 2678400); else session_set_cookie_params(2678400);`

Comment: @Mad Is this after session_start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session_destroy()` function to destroys all of the data associated with the current session and `setcookie()` function to set your cookie expiration date in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser.

Something like:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) setcookie(session_name(), false);
session_destroy();
setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 3600);
);
session_start();
// do stuff
```

Comment: Mmh, thanks but I am not quite sure it could work. `session_destroy()` should be called after `session_start()`. In what I wrote, I successfully deleted the cookie when it existed but I could not give a new one. Your code also deletes existing cookies but does not give a new one to logged in users either... Calling `session_start()` before `session_destroy()` is not sufficient to make it work.